# How to reset php state after fork

Tags: php, constants, fork

Hypothetical scenario, I have these files:

file1.php:

```
#!/bin/php
<?php
echo "starting\n";
$pid = pcntl_fork();
define('ME', 'Parent');
if($pid == 0) {
    include 'file2.php';
    exit;
}
echo "I am: ".ME;
```

file2.php:

```
#!/bin/php
<?php
define('ME', 'File2');
echo "Defined: ".ME;
```

When I run file1.php, I get an error, because ME is already defined and you can't re-define a constant. How can I tell php to reset ALL defined constants and variables, so that it can include a new file without carrying anything over? As far as I can see, my only options is to use shell_exec or similar to run a shell command to start a new php process, but that seems really roundabout - is there any way to clear out existing defined constants?

My specific use case is a large framework with many files included at various stages, much of which I can't touch, so you can assume that the only thing I'm able to modify in the above example is the contents of the `if($pid == 0) { ... }` brackets.

Comment: `The pcntl_fork() function creates a child process that differs from the parent process **only** in its PID and PPID`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Yes, exactly. So both processes have the same constants defined. How do I un-define them?

Comment: Why not using fork() and then exec()?

Comment: There is no way to undefine the PHP constants. Such a feature will defeat their purpose of being **constant** i.e. not changeable.